# Set-PnPListItemPermission does not work

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a folder within the Documents list and I need to delete the inheritance and add a user with editing permissions, this is the code I try to use

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxx"
$ListName = "Documents"
$UserAccount = "xxxxx@xxxxx.com"
$Role = "Edit"

#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential

Try {
    #Connect to PNP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred

    #Try to Get the List
    $List = Get-PnPList -Identity $ListName

    #Try to Get the List Item
    $ListItem = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Id 10

    If($ListName, $ListItem)
    {
        #Set Permission in the List Item
        Set-PnPListItemPermission -List 'Documents' -Identity 10 -User $UserAccount -AddRole $Role -ClearExisting  
        Write-Host -f Green "Set Permission in the List Item!"
        }
    Else
    {    
        #Write-Host -f Yellow "Could not Find List '$ListName'"
    }    
}
catch {
    #write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

Comment: ok, whats the problem here ? is it not working ? any error?

Comment: Thank you for answering. doesn't work and doesn't give any mistakes

Comment: Did yo try my code?

Comment: I've tried your code and I get these errors
#PnP PowerShell to Set Item Level Permission 
The argument cannot be bound to the 'Group' parameter because it is null.
#PnP PowerShell to Change Folder Permissions in SharePoint Online 
The argument cannot be bound to the 'Identity' parameter because it is null.
Poor definition of variables maybe

Comment: yes, you need to give correct folder relative URL, list name and user account value.

Comment: $FolderRelativeURL with this definitive variable correctly works well
I have a doubt, the groups of this variable ($GroupName) have to be discharged somewhere

Comment: I have modified the code and removed $GroupName, which is not needed for your scenario.

Comment: Sorry I still have the same problem, the execution of the code does not give any error but the changes do not apply to the site

Answer (score 1):

**PnP PowerShell to Change Folder Permissions in SharePoint Online**

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "Site URL"
$ListName="Documents"
$FolderRelativeURL = "/sites/marketing/Shared Documents/2019"
$UserAccount = "XXX" 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential) 
#Get the Folder from URL
$Folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $FolderRelativeURL 
#Set Permission to Folder 
Set-PnPListItemPermission -List $ListName -Identity $Folder.ListItemAllFields -User $UserAccount -AddRole 'Contribute'
```

**PnP PowerShell to Set Item Level Permission**

```
#Config Variables 
$SiteURL = "https://crescenttech.sharepoint.com/sites/Marketing" 
$ListName ="Projects" 
$ListItemID ="1" 
$UserID="Peter@TheCrescentTech.com" 
#Connect to PnP Online 
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)     
#Grant permission to User 
Set-PnPListItemPermission -Identity $ListItemID -List $ListName -AddRole "Edit" -User $UserID
```

Comment: If this has helped you, kindly upvote and mark it as answer, so that it will be helpful for others too.